# @Autowired annotation does not work on amazon swf activity

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am developing an application managed by amazon simple workflow and spring 4 with annotation based dependency injection.

IMyActivity.java

```
package com.test.activities;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.Activities;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.ActivityRegistrationOptions;
@ActivityRegistrationOptions(defaultTaskScheduleToStartTimeoutSeconds = 3000,
                             defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 100)
@Activities(version="1.0")
public interface IMyActivity {
  String dofunc();
}
```

MyActivityImpl.java

```
package com.test.activities;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


import com.test.services.TransactionService;


@Component
public class MyActivityImpl implements IMyActivity {

  @Autowired
  private ITransactionService transactionService;

  @Override
  public String dofunc() {

    return transactionService.dosomething();
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when the activity is scheduled by swf,`ITransactionService` implementation is not getting injected and `transactionService`is null. However, everything works fine when the `IMyActivity myactivity` is `@Autowired` from anywhere else and is not called by swf.

Am I doing something wrong here? Please help.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/test.html#test.spring. This is the official amazon swf documentation for its integration using spring. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `MyActivityImpl` class located in package that specified in component scan settings. If you use java config:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "")
```

and if you use xml config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package=""/>
```